# RabbitMq managment portal not available remote

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2003

So i set up a rabbitmq server on  my dev machine for a test.

I also set up the management portal and a user.

Everything works fine when on the windows server (iis).
I can browse to

```
https://server-name.rnd:15672/
```

and i can log in with the user

But i can't to do this remotely from anywhere else meaning i'm not even getting the log in page.

I tried

. opening the ports 15672 & 5672 (inbound and outbound rules)

but nothing...

What else can i do ?

Comment: Wich user are you using?

Comment: not the guest guest account that is only supported for local usage i understand, but i made a new user witch has all the rights. But the problem is not the login screen but  the fact that i'm not even getting that far

Comment: Do you have your machine in cloud or any on premise location with location being different.

Comment: could be that there is an external firewall somewhere, i'm checking with our hardware guy ? waiting on an answer. i will let you know